# TypeScript type exclude null include undefined

Tags: typescript, nullable

According to

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype

> #### NonNullable
>
> Constructs a type by excluding null and undefined from Type.

Example

```
type T0 = NonNullable<string | number | undefined>;
//    ^ = type T0 = string | number
type T1 = NonNullable<string[] | null | undefined>;
//    ^ = type T1 = string[]
```

and I've read it's defined as:

```
type NonNullable<T> = T extends null ? never : T
```

Now, I want to exclude `null` but to include `undefined` that is required to my code.

How would you do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually the existing `NonNullable` is defined as `type NonNullable<T> = T extends null | undefined ? never : T;`. But you can create your own utility type like below, and use it.

```
type NonNullButUndefined<T> = T extends null ? never : T;

// Usage
type T = NonNullButUndefined<string | null | undefined>;
```

#### Usage:

[image: Usage]

Comment: Thanks, and I forgot to mention. What I exactly need is for any types but null, say `unknown` - `null`. What would you do?

Comment: I dont exactly understand. You mean you want to support unknown too?

Comment: It's like `type T = NonNullButUndefined<unknown>;` but for some readon, this becomes just `unknown`.